# Can we increase the contrast between Arqade and Meta.Arqade's icons?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, arqade-migration

I saw this in my inbox today.

[image]

Now, my screen cap + the imgur treatment appears to have enlarged the above picture, but when this was in my inbox, it was not readily obvious that one was for the main site and one was for the meta site.

The difference is there, but the majority of the Arqade favicon is white or dark blue (which appears black at a distance or small size) and I found it quite hard to tell which was which.

Might something be done to add a greater contrast between the two icons?

Comment: PS: [I found the culprit!](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4821/introducing-arqade#comment13951_4848) :P

Comment: Perhaps invert the Meta icon to a white ship on black square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an updated meta favicon will be in the next prod build.

Comment: Looks great! Nice job.